# C# - Access CRUD of a class given only the class name

Tags: c#

I am tasked with bridging the gap between two pieces of legacy code. I am not sure if it matters but the two pieces of legacy are written VB.Net that live in a separate DLL from the where my code will operate.

Leaving my bridge to the second piece of code is not an issue. My issue lies with the first segment of legacy code; the point at which I leave this code all I have to work with is the string name of the class in question; call it "Alpha".

I know I can use reflection to get the object:

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Alpha");
```

The problem is I cannot seem to access any of the methods of the class

```
obj.NewRow();
obj.Save();
```

I get compile errors stating that "'object' does not contain a definition for..." each of the methods i try and access.

I feel sure this is possible and I am probably going about it all wrong. I am obviously missing something, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Uh, maybe you should cast the object to the type you just instanced?

Comment: you'll probably need to cast the instance to the `Alpha` class. maybe instead of object you could try `var obj`

Comment: @Pikoh `var` probably wouldn't work, since there is no way to infer the type from its usage here

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. In fact I wanted to say `dynamic`, but it may not work either @TimothyGroote

Comment: @Pikoh, no i think dynamic *will* work come to think of it, but it's dangerous (in this context) and probably a bad idea.

Comment: I do not believe I can cast the instance since the class name string I receive will not always be the same. It could be any one of a dozen different class names. I will try dynamic and report back with results. thanks

Comment: @JeffMartinez theoretically, you could use reflection to determine what type to cast to ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the result to the appropriate type.

```
var obj = (Alpha)Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Alpha");
```

Otherwise, you only have an `object` (the type returned by `CreateInstance`).  If you don't have a reference to the class itself, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Alpha");
```

But be mindful that using `dynamic` you lose compile-time type checking.  The first solution is preferable for that reason.